# How to auto-wire a class' constructor that accepts two string

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I've been trying to figure out how to auto-wire the constructor of a class that accepts two strings. For now this is what I have.

This is the class:

```
public class Indexer {

    private String isbn;
    private String environment;

    //Getters and Setters here...

    @Autowired
    public Indexer(String isbn, String environment) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.environment = environment;
    }
}
```

Then this is the configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Indexer indexer() {
        //dunno what to do
    }
}
```

But I'm stuck on this part. The variables `isbn` and `environment` will come from a controller that has two request paramaters `isbn` and `environment`. Sort of like this:

```
@Controller
public class ContentController {

    @Autowired
    Indexer index;

    public void reindex(String isbn, String environment) {
        index.somefunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: When the two parameters come from the controller, why don't you pass them as parameters to index.somefunction() like this index.somefunction(isbn, enviroment)? You can't autowire attributes that are dynamically handled in your application.

Comment: Why do I feel like this is impossible to do because how do I inject something if the variables `isbn` and `environment` will only exist if the function from the controller is called.

Comment: @JakobEm yup just realized it by now.

Comment: So the two values should also be available without calling the controller ? Where should the initial values come from?

Comment: @JakobEm want to post that as an answer so I could mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: @JakobEm nope. It will only be available upon function call.

Comment: Already answered by someone else :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work like this, spring autowires on startup of the application, and you're trying to autowire when the application runs.

Its not clear who calls `public void reindex(String isbn, String environment)` method though. Maybe you should rewrite the indexer so that it would get `isbn` and `environment` as parameters:

```
class Indexer {
    public void someFunction(String isbn, String envrionment) {
       ...
    }
}

class ContentController {
   @Autowired Indexer indexer;

    public void reindex(String isbn, String environment) {
        index.somefunction(isbn, environment);
    }
}
```